# Unity IoC with ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container, asp.net-mvc-5

I cannot find a NuGet package for ASP.NET MVC5.  I tried installing Unity.Mvc4 but the package manager refuses to add Unity.Mvc4.dll as  reference, which is probably a good thing.

Suspect all I needed is UnityDependencyResolver so that I can set it up in Boostrapper like so:

```
  public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
        {
            var container = BuildUnityContainer();         
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
            return container;
        }
```

But this class is defined in Unity.Mvc4.dll.  Anyone using Unity with MVC5?  If so, how did you go about integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation of UnityDependencyResolver is simpler than I had imagined.

I downloaded the source from [CodePlex](https://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#source/Unity.Mvc/Src/) and just copied class into my project, then implemented Boostrapper.cs as usual.

Ensure your class is implementing interface **System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver** and not System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package now in NuGet for Unity.Mvc5 by Paul Hiles.